# Citrix cannot find libXp.so.6

Tags: libraries

I have recently installed Citrix but when running:

```
 CLIENT_EXEC="/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/wfcmgr"
 ldd ${CLIENT_EXEC}
```

I get

```
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77db000)
libXm.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXm.so.4 (0xf7520000)
libXp.so.6 => not found
libXpm.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4 (0xf750d000)
libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0xf7504000)
libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0xf74ea000)
libXmu.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXmu.so.6 (0xf74d1000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0xf74cd000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf74c7000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xf73bb000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf739f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf71f0000)
libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0xf7194000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf705f000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf704c000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xf7011000)
libXft.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXft.so.2 (0xf6ffb000)
libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0xf6fa0000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xf6f77000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0xf6f71000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77dc000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xf6f33000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf6f11000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xf6e71000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xf6e47000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xf6e3c000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf6e22000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf6ddc000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf6dd8000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf6dd0000)
```

as you can see `libXp.so.6` was not found.
I figured that this library is located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and all the other libraries are in `/usr/lib/i386-linuxpgnu`.
Can I somehow link the `libXp.so.6` to the other directory?

The output of `find / -name "*libXp*" -exec ls -l {} \; -print` is:

```
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2792 Dec 18  2013 /usr/share/man/man3/libXp.3Xp.gz
 /usr/share/man/man3/libXp.3Xp.gz
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 May  2  2012 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4 -> libXpm.so.4.11.0
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 67460 May  2  2012 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4.11.0
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4.11.0
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Jul 29 20:32 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6 -> ./libXp.so.6
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 35712 Dec 18  2013 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6.2.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6.2.0
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Dec 18  2013 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.so -> libXp.so.6.2.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.so
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 May  2  2012 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4 -> libXpm.so.4.11.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 May  2  2012 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so -> libXpm.so.4.11.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 72776 May  2  2012 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4.11.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4.11.0
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Dec 18  2013 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6 -> libXp.so.6.2.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 60508 Dec 18  2013 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.a
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.a
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 123452 May  2  2012 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.a
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.a
```

Here the second output:

```
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2792 Dec 18  2013 /usr/share/man/man3/libXp.3Xp.gz
 /usr/share/man/man3/libXp.3Xp.gz
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 May  2  2012 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4 -> libXpm.so.4.11.0
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 67460 May  2  2012 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4.11.0
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4.11.0
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 35712 Dec 18  2013 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6.2.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6.2.0
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Dec 18  2013 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.so -> libXp.so.6.2.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.so
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 May  2  2012 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4 -> libXpm.so.4.11.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 May  2  2012 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so -> libXpm.so.4.11.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 72776 May  2  2012 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4.11.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4.11.0
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Dec 18  2013 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6 -> libXp.so.6.2.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 60508 Dec 18  2013 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.a
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.a
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 123452 May  2  2012 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.a
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.a
```

I reinstalled Citrix 13.0 and now I receive this error:

[image: Citrix 13.0 error]

Comment: `libXp.so.6` is provided by the package `libxp6`. [See](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libxp.so.6&searchon=contents)

Comment: I have installed `libXp6`, `libXp6-dev` and `libXp6-dbg

Comment: Could you post `find / -name "*libXp*" -exec ls -l {} \; -print`?

Comment: Ok updated the output

Comment: i reinstalled everything and installed Citrix 13.0 again! Unfortunately this time I receive a differnt error -> updated in the post!

Comment: @wasp256: I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007052/gtk-warning-unable-to-locate-theme-engine-in-module-path-murrine-error-whi)

Comment: I read through it but how is that related to my 'ApplicationServers' error??

Comment: Sorry, @wasp256, I thought it was the same problem though on a different program, the error message is same as yours. In that case was resolved with the installation of the library libgtkmm-2.4-1c2

Answer (score 0):

There is a broken link:

```
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Jul 29 20:32 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6 -> ./libXp.so.6
```

I guess that you can fix it by running:

```
   sudo rm /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6      
   sudo ldconfig -v
```

This will update **ld.so** information. Here is [ldconfig manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/ldconfig.8.html) for more information.

Comment: I run the command with the following output http://pastebin.com/iQnKkk22 but I still get the some error

Comment: Sorry @wasp256, I did not see broken link. I updated my answer.

Comment: But the `libXp.so.6` is not in that directory?? I get `rm: cannot remove ‘/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Sorry, but in `find` output is present. You can see in your question. Could you redo `find` command and add (not override the first) the result?

Comment: Ok I added the output again

Comment: Could you post `strings /etc/ld.so.cache` output? It seems that program you run need 32bit library, in your system is present only 64bit version. Did installation process end well? Did you follow some manual?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the steps in [the wiki guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo)?  Also note that the wiki recommends 12.1 for Ubuntu 14.04.  Make sure you look at the steps for the version you are using.

Also, I noticed my launcher has a different command than yours:

`Exec=/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/wfcmgr -icaroot /opt/Citrix/ICAClient`

Comment: I have seen the wiki guide, but unfortunately I need the 13.0 receiver because the machine I have to connect too is only compatible with that one. I've tried your command but it gives me `-icaroot: command not found`